# returning embedded document from collection find

Tags: meteor

This Meteor code tries to return a cursor to the embedded documents referenced by the field `data`, then checks if it exists (because some times it does not exist in `ActiveTaskCol`) before returning this template helper method.

**added later**
The expected returned cursor will be used in the html {{#each data}} for more work hence the use of `.find` instead of `.findOne`.

The problem is that the if statement evaluates to true even though there is no `data` field in the `ActiveTaskCol`, I also tried `obj.count() > 0` which also true even though "data" field does not exist in the collection.
How can I fix this? Thanks

```
Template.index.helpers({
    taskInputs: function () {
        var ready = Meteor.subscribe('inputsCol').ready();
        var data = InputsCol.find({});

        var selectedTask = Session.get('taskSelected');
        var obj = ActiveTaskCol.find({action: selectedTask}, {field: {data: 1}});
        if (typeof obj != 'undefined') {  //<-always true --------------
            return {items: obj};
        } else {
            return {items: data, ready: ready};
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always true because, you are using `find`, which returns a cursor. Instead, you should use `findOne`, so that, it will return document or undefined, if there is no such document. I also suggest, you use `obj`, which checks for falsy values like `undefined`, `null`, `false` instead of `typeof obj != 'undefined'`

```
Template.index.helpers({
    taskInputs: function () {
        var ready = Meteor.subscribe('inputsCol').ready();
        var data = InputsCol.find({});

        var selectedTask = Session.get('taskSelected');
        var obj = ActiveTaskCol.findOne({action: selectedTask}, {field: {data: 1}});
        if (obj) {  
            return {items: obj};
        } else {
            return {items: data, ready: ready};
        }
    }
});
```

**Update:**
Based on your comments, you can use `obj.count()` to check whether there are documents matching your criteria.

```
Template.index.helpers({
    taskInputs: function () {
        var ready = Meteor.subscribe('inputsCol').ready();
        var data = InputsCol.find({});

        var selectedTask = Session.get('taskSelected');
        var obj = ActiveTaskCol.find({action: selectedTask}, {field: {data: 1}});
        if (obj.count() > 0) {  
            return {items: obj};
        } else {
            return {items: data, ready: ready};
        }
    }
});
```

**Update 2**

```
Template.index.helpers({
    taskInputs: function () {
        var ready = Meteor.subscribe('inputsCol').ready();
        var data = InputsCol.find({});

        var selectedTask = Session.get('taskSelected');
        var obj = ActiveTaskCol.find({
            action: selectedTask,
            data: { $exists: true }
        }, {
            field: {data: 1}
        });
        if (obj.count() > 0) {  
            return {items: obj};
        } else {
            return {items: data, ready: ready};
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Since I need to return {items: obj} if data field exists, Did you mean if(obj) since that will ensure it is not (undefined, null, false)? instead of what you typed if (!obj)? thx

Comment: The reason I used find instead of findOne is that I need the template helper to return a cursor so that a html template {{#each data}} can use it. Plus, I need to get a cursor for the embedded document referenced to by the field "data" and not the top level document.  p.s. thx for the fast fix of !obj :)

Comment: the "data" field does not exist but obj.count() returns more than 0 thus evaluates to true. Why is that? How can I "find" only the embedded document "data" and nothing if the field "data" does not exist?

Comment: If you want to return a document if data column exists, then you need to use `$exists` in your query selector.

Comment: @FredJ. Updated answer.